# StringFormat involvment is triggering TargetUpdated event

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, string-formatting

I have a `TextBox` bound to a `double` value. I have set the string format for the binding to `N2`. Now, when ever I make a change within the `TextBox` that is causing the `StringFormat` to kick in, `TargetUpdated` of the `TextBox` is being triggered. Here are some examples:

- 200.00 -> 2,000.00 (After adding a zero to 200, StringFormat needs to add the thousand separator)
- the same is for erasing a digit that require the separator to be removed
- adding or erasing a comma or a dot will cause the StringFormat to kick in and, well, format the number

I need either of these:

- prevent `TargetUpdated` from being triggered upon number formatting
- <s>a way to distinct the call within the `TargetUpdated` from times that the target has actually been updated</s> (*EDIT2)

Some things from the code that could cause this:

- the `TextBox` is within a `UserControl`, but I am setting `e.Handled` to `true` within its `TargetUpdated` event
- there are some mouse and keyboard events being called within the `UserControl` as well as in the parent form, but they do something only if some special key is being pressed

Here is the binding on the `UserControl`:

```
Text="{Binding SomeAmount, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat='{}{0:N2}'}"
```

Here for the `TextBox` within the `UserControl`:

```
Text="{Binding Text}"
```

I have a `DependencyProperty` called `Text` within my `UserControl`. Everything is working as I want it to, except the `TargetUpdated` call by the `StringFormat`. Tell me if you need some more of my code.

**EDIT1:**

`StringFormat` is causing both the `UserControl` as well as the `TextBox` `TargetUpdated` events to be triggered, so I don't think it is because of the control nesting. Also, `TargetUpdated` is being called before the `TextUpdated` event.

**EDIT2:**

Both `object sender` and `DataTransferEventArgs e` objects are the same when actual target has been updated and when `StringFormat` has made some edits. And since distincting the two calls is not possible, I have to prevent the event from being triggered somehow.

Comment: Do you really need the StringFormat to be applied when typing into the TextBox?

Comment: I would like it to. But I am open to solutions that only format it once, when updating the source. It would also need to be two-way bound to the underlying `double` property even if user writes "25.0.0,00" or "2500" for the value 2.500,00.

Comment: And why do you need to handle TargetUpdated? What are you doing in the event handler?

Comment: I am saving the initial value of the `TextBox` so I can change the `Background` if the `Text` is not the same as it was when loaded. Just a feedback for the user.

Comment: Okay, I figured it is a global issue for binding to an `integer` or a `double` property. I will post another question and close this one.